# Project won't build - missing dependencies (Xcode can't download them)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git, xcode5

I got a project from other developer, and when I try to build it in Xcode, it says

`missing AFNetworking.h`

So when I checked the `Source Control` menu I see this:

[image]

All of them are greyed out so I guess they are not downloaded. So I click on one, there are two options - `Check out` and `Settings`.

When I clicked check out I got presented with loading screen and then this:

[image]

I can't select anything there, the next is not highlighted, can't select the tick.
So I have a not working project and I don't know how to fix it.

How can this be resolved?

I checked - I have access to the git repository those .git files are, but this doesn't help much.
I tried checking if the project was under git, but it says not a git repository in any of the folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error - I was behind proxy and git could not reach repositories.